# Is the PKK and PYD's political outlook unpopular among Iraqi Kurds?

Tags: parties, iraq, kurdistan

The [Kurdistan Democratic Solution Party](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kurdistan_Democratic_Solution_Party) is active in the Iraqi Kurdish autonomy zone; and it seems to be the counterpart of the PYD in Syria and the PKK in Turkey. The party failed rather miserably in 2 KRG parliamentary election campaigns in recent years.

Is it because PKK/PYD-like positions are unpopular among Iraqi Kurds, or is it other reasons, such as: Repression of the party/movement by the KRG and possibly other forces precludes; lack of awareness to this movement's legacy, positions and outlook; existence of other parties in Iraq which are close enough in their positions, which do not exist in Syria and Turkey?

... No need for a binary answer of course, please explain this as you see it.

Comment: Seems like a very leading question. There's plenty of other reason for election failure by a party

Comment: @user4012: That wasn't the intent... see edit.

Comment: I suspect it's relevant that the PKK is more than twice as old, and that much of it's support seems tied to the personal charismatic leadership of Öcalan. Combined with other factors you mention, I hardly find it surprising that the PÇDK hasn't gained much ground.

Comment: @BrianZ: But Ocalan has been in prison for decades... also, why does it matter that the PKK is older?

Comment: Öcalan's imprisonment has arguably made him a kind of martyr and ironically strengthened the PKK. I suspect it may matter that they are older both because it can take time to build a party and also because they established themselves in a very different historical and geo-political context (the PKK has Soviet support during its formative period).

Comment: @BrianZ: But why would both of these points make the PKK's politics popular in Syria, yet unpopular in Iraq? They're both not-Turkey, after all? ... Well, I guess it comes back to the fact that the PKK had been active in Syria for a while, and not so much (or not at all?) in Iraq.

Comment: @einpoklum I get the sense that there are a lot of family ties and people moving back and forth between the Kurdish regions of Turkey and Syria but less so in the case of Iraq, which may be relevant. But everything I'm saying in these comments is all pretty speculative, it would nice to be find a good source that really addresses this question and I'm not finding anything so far.

Comment: @BrianZ: How many family ties could there be? We're talking about millions of people all counted...

Comment: Anecdotally I've heard that most Kurds living near the Turkey-Syria border have family members on the other side, but have no idea if this has been documented.

Comment: @einpoklum As I look into this further, I would ask you to elaborate what exactly you mean by "PKK/PYD-like positions", as it's not so clear to me that the PDK are that fundamentally different.

Comment: @BrianZ: Against a Kurdish state, for a federated, de-centralized social order, councilism, massive focus on women's involvement and representation, inter-ethnic power-sharing. Stuff like that.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not terribly knowledge about the region and am figuring out a lot of this as I go, so I welcome any informed challenge on anything I say here. But my hypothesis right now is that it would be mistaken to assume that popular support for the PKK in Turkey and and the YPG in Syria are primarily based on their political ideologies. In each country, **Kurds in general support whatever party or parties have been best able to deliver concrete autonomy and security over time,** largely regardless of ideology.

When the PKK formed **in Turkey** during the 1970s, it was a Leninist national liberation movement which enjoyed Soviet support in a struggle for independence against the Turkish state. The present ideology of the PKK (and later the YPG in Syria) began to emerge much later on, in [a moment of crisis in the late 1990s and early 2000s](https://biblio.ugent.be/publication/3101181/file/6783510.pdf) when leader [Abdullah  Öcalan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abdullah_%C3%96calan) was captured and imprisoned. It was primarily from prison that Öcalan began to propose new ideologies like "democratic confederalism" and "[jineology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jineology) (a kind of feminism). In formulating these ideas, he was reflecting not only on Western authors like Murray Bookchin and Immanuel Wallerstein but also on the practice that emerged of necessity int the 1990s when the PDK was basically defeated militarily and sought new ways to build mass support.

The [PDK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kurdistan_Democratic_Party) **in Iraq** predates the PKK by decades, and the [PUK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patriotic_Union_of_Kurdistan) is only slightly newer than the PKK. Both started with conventional leftist-nationalist ideologies similar to that of the PKK. Their evolution over time is complex but both have built up and maintained significant bases of support over decades. Most importantly, these parties were not defeated to the extent that the PKK was. These parties became the overseers of a Kurdish region with political autonomy that the PKK never managed to deliver.

**In Syria**, I think the most important bit of historical background to note may be that the Kurdish population is smaller here then in the other countries. The [PDKS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kurdistan_Democratic_Party_of_Syria) has a similar history to the other Kurdish nationalist parties and also predates the PKK. I suspect an important part of the rise of the YPG may have to do with the relative weakness of the PDKS. The YPG is primarily a militia rather than a political party and it formed quite recently.

Now in this overall context, I think we can better understand **the relative failure of the PÇDK to gain support in Iraq**. It formed in 2002, when the PKK was in the process of re-inventing itself with a new ideology. That ideology seems to have been a major inspiration for PÇDK to form. But unlike the PKK, it had multiple established competitors in a position of relative strength. The YPG in Syria emerged later and adopted similar ideology, but security, not political ideology, was its primary reason for being.

Comment: The YPG is a militia, but the political party is PYD, and it's the senior coalition partner in Rojava.

Comment: Good point, I will edit if I have time, but my interpretation wouldn't change fundamentally. The PYD emerged in a very different situation and unless I am again mistaken, there was no well-established competitor in place when it formed.